# Loop issue not adding up correctly

Tags: android, loops, textview

New to android development and i have a simple question.
I have a text view that keeps track of points.  I just need to be able to add 20 more points to the total and then display it in the text view.  For example if its 100 in the text view, i wanna add 20 then show it as 120. Do i need a loop for this? This is what i have but it only adds 20 then nothing else.

```
        int points =0;
        points = points + 20;
        textView2.setText(Integer.toString(points));
```

Comment: What is not working? This code should add 20 + 0 and display 20. What eactly is a problem?

Comment: It works yes but I need to keep adding 20 to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int current = Integer.parseInt(textView2.getText());
int total = current + points;
textView2.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: @apksrc you're welcome, please let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

```
int points = 0;
while(true){
textView2.setText(points.ToString());
points = popints + 20;
}
```

This will add 20 for infinity (this way this loop doesnt stop. Yoi may add some condition like:

```
if(points > 1000){
break;
}
```

to stop it or use `for` loop instead of `while` loop